# How to retrieve data from Elasticsearch sub-aggregate search queries

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying a multiple sub aggregation query to retrieve a query result on my Elasticsearch index.

The query looks somewhat like this.

```
{
  "query": SEARCH_BODY,
  "aggs": {'aggregate1': 
            {'terms': 
                 {'field': 'field1', 'size': 10000},
             'aggs': {'aggregate2':
                          {'terms': 
                                  {'field': 'field2', 'size': 10000},
                           'aggs': {'aggregate3':
                                        {'terms': 
                                             {'field': 'field3', 'size': 10000},
                                        'aggs': {'column1': 
                                                     {'sum': 
                                                          {'field': 'field4'}
                                                      }
                                                 }
                                         }
                                    }
                           }
                      }
             }
        }
}
```

The result for this query is:

```
temp = {'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
        'sum_other_doc_count': 0,
        'buckets': [{'key': 'A', 'doc_count': 9,
                     'aggregate': {
                         'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
                         'sum_other_doc_count': 0,
                         'buckets': [{'key': 'B',
                                      'doc_count': 1,
                                      'aggregate': {
                                          'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
                                          'sum_other_doc_count': 0,
                                          'buckets': [{
                                              'key': 'C',
                                              'doc_count': 1,
                                              'column': {
                                                  'value': 12345}
                                          }]
                                      }
                                      }]
                     }
                     }]
        }
```

I am looking to form a table of this result just like a groupby would result in a SQL query.

```
aggregate1 | aggregate2 | aggregate3 | column1
   A             B            C         1234
   A             B            D          431
```

Something like this. Is there a better way to do other than parsing the above result and converting it into a dataframe or a json object.
Does elasticsearch have any inbuilt methods that sends the `aggs` as a `source` key or the main result?

Answer (score 0):

At best, you can get a JSON object of this format:

```
{
  "columns" : [
    {
      "name" : "column1",
      "type" : "long"
    },
    {
      "name" : "COUNT(*)",
      "type" : "long"
    }
  ],
  "rows" : [
    [
      "One",
      1
    ],
    [
      "Two",
      5
    ]
  ]
}
```

Using SQL query:

```
POST _sql
{
  "query": "SELECT column1, COUNT(*) FROM \"my-index\" GROUP BY column1"
}
```